# UNIX grep command (grep -v grep)

Tags: unix, grep

I was going through something and found this which I could not understand,

**grep -v grep**

What does this signify? I know that `-v` switch will select all the lines that do not match. But why the second `grep`?

This is the full command:

```
ps -ef | grep rsync -avz \
| grep oradata${DAY}_[0-1][0-9] \
| grep -v grep \
| awk '{print $2}' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`grep` when used with `ps -ef` also outputs the `grep` used for filtering the output of `ps -ef`.

`grep -v grep` means that do not include the `grep` used for filtering in the command output.

You can also avoid `grep` in the results by using a `regex` pattern.
For example, in the following example you won't need a `grep -v grep` to avoid `grep` in the output:

```
ps -ef | grep [r]sync
```

Here's another example, showing different commands and their output, notice the first one where `grep` is also in the output whereas in the last two `grep` is not printed in the output:

```
$ ps -ef | grep ipython
  501 18055 18031   0 12:44AM ttys000    0:00.00 /bin/bash /Users/amit/anaconda/bin/python.app /Users/amit/anaconda/bin/ipython notebook --profile=ocean
  501 18056 18055   0 12:44AM ttys000    0:00.85 /Users/amit/anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python /Users/amit/anaconda/bin/ipython notebook --profile=ocean
  501 18067 18031   0 12:44AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep ipython

$ ps -ef | grep ipython | grep -v grep
  501 18055 18031   0 12:44AM ttys000    0:00.00 /bin/bash /Users/amit/anaconda/bin/python.app /Users/amit/anaconda/bin/ipython notebook --profile=ocean
  501 18056 18055   0 12:44AM ttys000    0:00.85 /Users/amit/anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python /Users/amit/anaconda/bin/ipython notebook --profile=ocean

$ ps -ef | grep [i]python
  501 18055 18031   0 12:44AM ttys000    0:00.00 /bin/bash /Users/amit/anaconda/bin/python.app /Users/amit/anaconda/bin/ipython notebook --profile=ocean
  501 18056 18055   0 12:44AM ttys000    0:00.85 /Users/amit/anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python /Users/amit/anaconda/bin/ipython notebook --profile=ocean
```

Comment: Great. Just what I wanted.